# Creating a boxed output with macro style

Tags: macros, verbatim

I'm trying to get a specific output and for now it's not as I wish.

Desired output:

[image: This is the result i'm looking for]

It's for a TugBoat article. For now I have this solution :

```
    \documentclass{ltugboat} 
        \usepackage{fancyvrb}

        \begin{document}
        Some text
        \begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
            \actsymb[<ll>][<ul>]{<symbol>}{<lr>}[<ur>]
        \end{Verbatim}
        \end{document}
```

Actual output:

[image: actual output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fancyvrb` allows you to escape to regular LaTeX macros inside the verbatim content.  This is described nicely in the manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass{ltugboat} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand\param[1]{\textrm{$\langle$\textit{#1}$\rangle$}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,commandchars=+\(\)]
  \actsymb[+param(ll)][+param(ul)]{+param(symbol)}{+param(lr)}[+param(ur)]
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tks, it's perfect!

Comment: The `ltugboat` class provides `\meta` for your hand made `\param`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `verbatimbox` with a little `\catcode` magic sprinkled on top.  In doing it this way, the verbatim input needs no escape characters, but is instead put in directly as (in this case) `\actsymb[<ll>][<ul>]{<symbol>}{<lr>}[<ur>]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\catcode`>=\active %
\catcode`<=\active %
\def\openesc{\itshape\rmfamily$\langle$}
\def\closeesc{\/$\rangle$\upshape\ttfamily}
\def\vbdelim{%
  \catcode`<=\active %
  \catcode`>=\active %
  \def<{\openesc}%
  \def>{\closeesc}%
}
\catcode`>=12 %
\catcode`<=12 %
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\vbdelim]
\actsymb[<ll>][<ul>]{<symbol>}{<lr>}[<ur>]
\end{verbbox}
\fbox{\theverbbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]